# Select values that meet both cases in A and B at the same time (WHERE condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to choose only number of people who are users of **dbo.D_drug.ATC7_code LIKE 'A10B%'** and **dbo.D_drug.ATC7_code LIKE 'C10%'** at the same time. So if patient didnt using both medication concurrently/together, he must be eliminated from the result.
Below is my demand, but i guess, its not correct. Thanks for help!.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.drugconsumption.PatientDim AS ID_patient,
       dbo.drug.code,
       dbo.drug.description
                    
FROM   data_star.dbo.F_drugconsumption
            LEFT JOIN dbo.D_drug ON DrugDim = dbo.D_drug.id
                    
WHERE ( dbo.D_drug.ATC7_code LIKE 'A10B%'
        OR 
        dbo.D_drug.ATC7_code LIKE 'C10%' 
      )
AND  ( dbo.F_drugconsumption.DateDim >='20200101' )
AND  ( dbo.F_drugconsumption.DateDim <='20201231' )
AND  ( dbo.F_drugconsumption.AgeDim <='125' )
                    
GROUP BY       
      dbo.F_drugconsumption.PatientDim, 
      dbo.D_drug.code,
      dbo.D_drug.description
                               
HAVING  COUNT (dbo.D_drug.ATC7_code) = 2
```

Comment: "i guess, its not correct" what makes you guess? And how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Not related to the issue, but no need for *both* DISTINCT and GROUP BY the same columns. They do the same thing, so use one or the other.  Also, most of those parentheses in the WHERE clause are unnecessary . Only the ones surrounding the OR condition are required.

Comment: When a drug-code starts with `A10B`, it cannot also start with `C10`. The words in your question should also read `or`, and your SQL seems OK.

Comment: `i guess, its not correct` Since we can't see your data, we have no idea what that means ;-) Please post a) some sample rows and b) the expected result and how it differs from the actual result.